# How does the num_words parameter of keras Tokenizer work?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, text-processing

When tokenizing a text sequence in keras using Tokenizer class, we can specify a param 'num_words' to consider only the [top] n words in the dataset. My doubt here is

1. What does the [top] values mean? Does it mean the frequency of the word or any other value like tf-idf?
2. Is the [top] value computed on each document level or by considering the entire dataset?

Directing to any good resources or explanation with example will be very useful.

Comment: 1. It means frequency. 2. it is computed based on the whole document. Read [this](https://www.amazon.com/Deep-Learning-Python-Francois-Chollet/dp/1617294438) book.

Comment: @Vlad, thanks for the response, if its frequency won't the stop words like 'the', 'in' etc., will be considered in larger percent. Won't we miss the unique words that occurs min times and provide more meaning. I am following the same book, but could get my head around this.

Comment: Wasn't me, it was @Vlad

Answer (score 0):

Here the [top] denotes the frequency of the word on the entire dataset.It considers the (num_words) number of words based on the descending frequency of each word.The doubt i had was that, it is obvious that stopwords words will occur more times than other words and thus most of the stop words will make it to the top (num_words) words, but to handle this we first remove the stopwords and then apply tokenization.